# Angular test case returns TypeError: _this.reCaptchaApi.render is not a function

Tags: jasmine, angular5, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have implemented the ngx-captcha in Angular 6 Reactive Forms. The functionality is working fine for me but when I run the unit test case, the test case fails with the following message:

> TypeError: _this.reCaptchaApi.render is not a function.

I implemented the ngx-captcha (visible type) in two components. For both the component functionality is working fine for me, but during unit test case run I am getting the above mentioned error.

I tried with the following:

captcha-test.html

```
<ngx-recaptcha2 #captchaElem [siteKey]="captchaSiteKey" 
formControlName="captcha"> </ngx-recaptcha2>
```

captca-test.ts

```
export class CaptchaTestComponent implements OnInit {
  validSiteKey: string = environment.validSiteKey;
  captchaExampleForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.captchaExampleForm = this.fb.group({
      captcha: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

exampleFormSubmit(){
return false;
   }
}
```

//captcha-test.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from 
"@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { CaptchaTestComponent } from "./captcha-test.component";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform- 
browser/animations";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule } 
from "@angular/material";
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { TestConstants } from "src/app/test/constants";
import { NgxCaptchaModule } from "ngx-captcha";

describe("CaptchaTestComponent", () => {
jasmine.getEnv().allowRespy(true);
let fixture: ComponentFixture<CaptchaTestComponent>;

beforeEach(async(function () {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, NgxCaptchaModule],
  providers: [FormBuilder
  ],
  declarations: [CaptchaTestComponent]
  }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(function () {
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CaptchaTestComponent);
 this.component = fixture.componentInstance;
 this.component.captchaExampleForm.controls["captcha"].setValue(TestConstan ts.validCaptcha); //manually set a string data as input data.

fixture.detectChanges();
});

it("should init component properly", function () {
  this.component.ngOnInit();
  expect(this.component.captchaExampleForm).toBeDefined();
});

it("should return submit as false when we submit the form", async 
  function () {
    const result = await this.component.exapmleFormSubmit();
    expect(result).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

I am using "ngx-captcha": "^5.0.4" version with Angular 6.

Comment: Please include the entire .spec file you have attempted.

Comment: I add the .spec file on the question section. Thank you.
@dmcgrandle

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is by far the cleanest solution, simply use the ng-mocks package and mock the NgxCaptchaModule in your imports.

```js
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // other imports
        MockModule(NgxCaptchaModule),
      ],
      declarations: [
        SignUpComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Protip: mock all your components and modules. Using this strategy will increase the isolation of your tests in components

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a timing issue.  I put what you have posted so far into a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54146810?file=app/captcha-test.component.spec.ts) to reproduce your issue.  As you can see in the StackBlitz, both tests are now passing.

The change I made to the test suite was to change the order of how you called `fixture.detectChanges()` in the second `beforeEach()`.  Before the change it looked like this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CaptchaTestComponent);
  this.component = fixture.componentInstance;
  this.component.captchaExampleForm.controls["captcha"].setValue(TestConstants.validCaptcha); //manually set a string data as input data.
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

And after the change it looks like this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CaptchaTestComponent);
  this.component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  this.component.captchaExampleForm.controls["captcha"].setValue(TestConstants.validCaptcha); //manually set a string data as input data.
});
```

The reason this is significant is because `fixture.detectChanges()` calls `ngOnInit()`, and you set up your form inside of `ngOnInit()`.  If you try and modify the form with `setValue` before it is set up, it will not work.  Chicken and egg problem.  :)

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is not working, we are still getting the same render error but sometimes it is passing so is there a possibility of any race conditions while tests are executing?

Comment: Interesting.  It seems to be passing consistently in the StackBlitz.  Perhaps you could FORK the StackBlitz to your own account and update with all the data from your component and template.  There may be something in that code causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by overriding the module which contains the ngx-recaptcha2 component.

MockComponent for Recaptcha V2

```js
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from "@angular/core";
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";
import { MockControlValueAccessor } from "./control_value_accessor.mock";

@Component({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
    selector: "ngx-recaptcha2",
    template: "<div></div>",
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => MockRecaptchaV2Component),
            multi: true
        },
    ]
})
export class MockRecaptchaV2Component extends MockControlValueAccessor {

    @Input() siteKey: string;
}
```

```html
<ngx-recaptcha2 #captchaElem [siteKey]="captchaSiteKey" formControlName="captcha"></ngx-recaptcha2>
```

Recaptcha is using formControlName so we need following mock class.

```js
import { ControlValueAccessor } from "@angular/forms";

export class MockControlValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    writeValue(obj: any): void {
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    }
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    }
}
```

We need to now override NgxCaptchaModule module using the following code.

```js
beforeEach(async(function () {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgxCaptchaModule],
      declarations: [SignupComponent, MockRecaptchaV2Component],
    }).overrideModule(NgxCaptchaModule, {
      remove: {
        // SignupComponent is needed as ReCaptcha2Component is used as child component inside SignupComponent
        declarations: [SignupComponent, ReCaptcha2Component], 
        exports: [SignupComponent, ReCaptcha2Component]
      }
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```